# SSH key authentication not working in Tera Term

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair, teraterm

I'm creating a CDK deployment to automate the deployment of a server. This is my code so far:

```
    let keyPair = new ec2.CfnKeyPair(this, "PublicEC2Key", {
      keyName: "public-ec2-key",
      tags: [new cdk.Tag("Name", `public-ec2-key`)],
    });

    // Create security group
    const publicEC2SG = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, `publicEC2SG`, {
      vpc: vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
      description: `Public CLC instance Security Group`,
      securityGroupName: `clc-public-ec2-sg`,
    });
    publicEC2SG.addIngressRule(
      ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),
      ec2.Port.tcp(22),
      "SSH from anywhere"
    );      

    // Launch EC2 instance in the public subnet (to be able to access it via SSH)
      let ec2_public = new ec2.Instance(this, "PublicEC2", {
        vpc: vpc,
        vpcSubnets: {
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        },
        instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
          ec2.InstanceClass.T2,
          ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO
        ),
        role: roleEC2,
        machineImage: ec2.MachineImage.latestAmazonLinux2023(),
        instanceName: `clc-public-ec2`,
        keyName: keyPair.keyName,
        securityGroup: publicEC2SG,
      });
```

After correctly deploying the VPC and the instance I can see both the instance in the console as well as the key pair. I then go to the
[Parameter store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuSML.png) from where I copy the key and create a new file named public-ec2-key.pem where I paste the certificate code (from -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- to -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- included).

I change the permissions of the file to:

chmod 400 public-ec2-key.pem

Finally I try to connect to the EC2 instance using Tera Term and the .pem file created but it returns an  [authentication error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymqCI.png).

The instance is accesible via SSH, but I cannot authenticate correctly. I'm I missing a step?

Thank you and best regards!

UPDATE: When I try connecting through ssh command using the linux terminal directly it works:
 `ssh -i "public-ec2-key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

It's there anything I need to configure in my TeraTerm?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to use rsa-sha2-256 or rsa-sha2-512. This isn't supported by the current version of Tera Term. Try Tera Term 5 RC 5.0 beta1, which does.